# Get info from the ip&port inserted on url

Tags: php, get, ip, info

I am trying to make script, I want to show the info from the gameserver ip inserted from the URL.

In current config I have:

```
<?php
define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: SOURCE );  
define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', '123.45.67.890' ); 
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', 12345); 
?>
```

and i tried like this:

```
<?php

define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: SOURCE );  

    if (isset($_GET['ip'])){
        $ip = $_GET['ip'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['port'])){
        $port = $_GET['port'];
    }

define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $ip ); 
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', $port );     
?>
```

to be like

```
http://localhost/".$ip.":".$port.
```

instead of a fixed ip. inserted on "define"

Answer (score 0):

You can't have you url as `localhost/$ip:$port`

You will need it as `localhost/addr=$IP:$PORT` because you are using `$_GET`

Modify your code with this code below:

```
<?php

define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: SOURCE );  

    if (isset($_GET['addr'])){
        $addr = $_GET['addr'];
        $addrarray = explode(':', $myString);
        $ip = $addrarray[0];
        $port = $addrarray[1];
    }

define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $ip ); 
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', $port ); 

?>
```

Now have your address as this:

I am using an example ip: 192.168.0.0
and an example port: 1234

```
localhost/addr=192.168.0.0:1234
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: so it will be like: <?php
error_reporting(-1);
require __DIR__ . '/SourceQuery/SourceQuery.class.php';

define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery :: SOURCE );  

    if (isset($_GET['addr'])){
        $addr = $_GET['addr'];
        $addrarray = explode(':', $myString);
        $ip = $addrarray[0];
        $port = $addrarray[1];
    }

define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', $ip ); 
define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', $port );
 
 $Query = new SourceQuery( );
 
 try
 {
  $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );
  $players_online = $Query->GetInfo()['Players'];